# Order Query Results aside from ASC and DESC

Tags: soql, query

I have a query that returns the following results:

- Apple
- Banana
- Grape
- Pomelo

Is there a way to make the "Grape" appear on top of the results?

Adding a new field to be used as an ordering identifier isn't feasible on our end. I'm afraid the ASC/DESC functions seems to not work here as well.

Any ideas/feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the only options you have left here are to

- do the ordering yourself in the presentation layer (i.e. through javascript)
- do the ordering yourself in Apex using a wrapper class and implementing the `Comparable` interface

Implementing the `Comparable` interface allows you to use `List.sort()` (which always sorts in ascending order, but you have explicit control of what "ascending" means).

A basic example:

```java
public class MySort implements Comparable {
    private static Map<String, Integer> foodOrder = new Map<String, Integer>{
        'grape' => 1,
        'apple' => 2,
        'pomelo' => 3,
        'banana' => 4,
        // The mapping here doesn't need to be unique
        'orange' => 4
    }

    // Some SObject, any SObject
    public Asset foodstuff;

    public MySort(Asset givenData){
        foodstuff = givenData;
    }

    // We need to implement the compareTo() method to satisfy the requirements of
    //   the Comparable interface
    public Integer compareTo(Object otherObj){
        MySort otherSort = (MySort)otherObj;

        Integer thisFood, otherFood;
        thisFood = MySort.foodOrder.get(foodstuff.Food_Name__c);
        otherFood = MySort.foodOrder.get(otherSort.Food_Name__c);

        // Pretty self evident
        // If the value for this instance is greater, return 1
        // If the value for the other instance is greater, return -1
        // To get "descending" order, you'd just flip the sign on the returned integer
        //   (or reverse the greater than & less than comparisons)
        if(thisFood > otherFood){ return 1; }
        else if(thisFood < otherFood) {  return -1; }

        // Not greater than and not less than means the two items are equal
        //   and we should return 0
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Which you would use like so

```java
List<MySort> myData = new List<MySort>{
    new MySort(new Asset(Food_Name__c = 'banana')),
    new MySort(new Asset(Food_Name__c = 'apple')),
    new MySort(new Asset(Food_Name__c = 'grape')),
    new MySort(new Asset(Food_Name__c = 'apple')),
    new MySort(new Asset(Food_Name__c = 'orange'))
};

myData.sort();

for(MySort sortItem :myData){
    system.debug(sortItem.foodstuff);
}
// should print
// grape, apple, apple, banana, orange
// or grape, apple, apple, orange, banana
```

Comment: Thank you, Derek! Your information is very clear and easy to follow :D
More power to you!